# VBA array runtime error 6, overflow

Tags: vba

I have following functions:

```
Function ArrayLength(arr() As Double) As Integer
    Dim len As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    len = UBound(arr) - LBound(arr)
    ArrayLength = len

End Function

'Print on console array
Sub PrintArray(arr() As Double, column As Integer)
    Dim len As Integer
    len = ArrayLength(arr)

    For i = 0 To len - 1
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 2, column).Value = arr(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

My array has more than 200000 elements, and when I try to print it, it show me next error:
[image: Run-time error '6': Overflow]

Comment: Overflow: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264525(v=vs.60).aspx 
  `Integer Integer value (2 bytes) in the range: -32768 to 32767.` `Long  Integer value (4 bytes) in the range: -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.`

Comment: I changed integer to long, it works, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outside the fact, that you should use `long` and not `integer`, your formula for array length is a bit wrong. It returns one less. Take a look at this code:

```
Function ArrayLength(arr) As Long

    Dim k As Long
    Dim i As Long

    k = UBound(arr) - LBound(arr)
    ArrayLength = k

End Function

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim arr() As Variant
    arr = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
    Debug.Print ArrayLength(arr)

End Sub
```

It will return 8, while the answer should be 9. In order to get the length, simply write `Debug.Print UBound(arr) + 1` to get the length.